# MS Access VBA to export a filtered form to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Here's one that's been bugging me for about a month...

I have a form that allows users to filter records, simple enough. But I want to give them the option to export the filtered records to Excel. I don't want to use the docmd.outputTo due to it won't filter the records, it puts all of the records in the file. I've looked around and found some code, but the problem is that it outputs EVERYTHING on the form. My goal is to output the filtered data into a new excel sheet. But I am still very new and struggling with the code. I am attaching the image  for the error (Below) and the code
thanks for the help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk917.png)

```
Private Sub cmdExport_Click()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlBook As Object
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Dim i As Integer

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
 'This selects form

sql = Forms("ReportForm13").Form.RecordSource 'Your record source if not a subform
'Set rs = CurrentDb

For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
xlBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i) = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name 'Write Field names to Excel
Next i
xlBook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs 'Import the recordset data through Excel

' You can add whatever other formatting you want by running Excel VBA throught the xlApp object

xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, exactly.  It's basically what Hira Iftikhar said, and it looks like this.

```
Private Sub cboFilterIsCorporate_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = Me.RecordSource
strSQL = "Select * From " & strSQL & " WHERE " & Me.Filter

With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryTest")
   .SQL = strSQL
End With

' now export the query  with critera to excel
Dim strOutFile As String

strOutFile = "C:\your_path\Test.xlsx"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
      "qryTest", strOutFile, True

End Sub
```

Access View:

[image]

Excel Before:

[image]

Excel After:

[image]

click the form > add a button > click the button and click 'ok' then click 'cancel' > right-click the button and click 'Build Event' > click 'Code Builder' > finally...paste the code that I gave you into the Window that opens.  Make a few very minor changes (should be obvious...the name of the click event).  Now, you should be good to go!!  Post back if you have additional questions!!  Otherwise, please update my answer to acknowledge that this is helpful to others.  Thanks!!

Comment: Love the code examples really help me thankyou so much!

Comment: Hey, I m trying to implement the code you shared with me so kindly and i am having an issue snapshot below

Comment: I am trying to implement the code however I am getting error character found after SQL and it highlights this.SQL = strSQL

Comment: I just made a few small updates.  It definitely works!  Remember, add a break point in the VBA code and hit the F8 key over and over and over, so you can step through the code line by line.  That way, you can see how everything works, and if you get an error, you can debug the issue pretty easily.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this. I am hitting an error and it says item not found in this line of code: With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Report13")

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter in form as criteria in query and can instead export that query into excel. It will just export filtered records.

Comment: THAT'S QUACK TASTIC THANK YOU BOTH!

Comment: how do i do that though do i call out my actual query that i am pulling data from?